# Sort deeply nested data extracted using mongoose filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I use mongoose filter to get data nested in MongoDB document. How to sort the result and is the method currently used to extract data efficient enough(Please suggest some solution or resources to study if not)?

```
User.findOne({
UserID: SomeID
}, (err, user) => {
userData = user.userData.filter(userData => {
  if (userData.Time.getTime() >= startTime && userData.Time.getTime() <= endTime) {
    return userData;
  }
});

res.json(userData);

});
```

How to sort the result(userData) by date in MongoDB?

Comment: Can you post a sample user data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

> Rather then you are filter the data based upon some date.You can do the
>   same thing in Mongodb because Mongodb written in C++ so that is much faster
>   by performance

```
User.findOne({
        $and: [{
            UserID: SomeID
        }, {
            startDate: {
                $lte: new Date()
            }
        }, {
            endDate: {
                $gte: new Date()
            }
        }]
    }, {}, {
        lean: true,
        sort: {
            startDate: -1 //Sort by Date Added DESC
        }
    }(err, user) => {
        err ? res.json(err) : res.json(user);
    });
```

Comment: UserData is nested. {user: [ {userData:[{time:Something}] }] }. This is just a sample. Real data is even further nested. This is the only reason I used this. Is it possible to do it directly in mongodb?